# Windows Powershell - How to Extract Specific SMART Info?

Tags: powershell, status, hard-drive, solid-state-drive

Sorry, I'm trying to understand powershell, and would appreciate some help. I am looking to extract specific SMART values. I know I can extract basic information from SMART using:

```
get-physicaldisk -serialnumber <serial nubmer> | get-storagereliabilitycounter | select-object -Property PowerOnHours,ReadErrorsCorrected,ReadErrorsTotal,ReadErrorsUncorrected,Temperature,TemperatureMax,Wear | out-file smart.txt
```

But `get-storagereliabilitycounter` is missing some S.M.A.R.T. values, in particular I'd like to get the LBA's written which is hex `0xF1`.

I did find:

```
(Get-WMIObject -Namespace root\WMI -Class MSStorageDriver_AtapiSmartData).VendorSpecific[115]
```

`115` is apparently temperature which is SMART hex `0xBE` but in decimal it is `190` so not sure what to make of it. Also, how do I select a specific disk with this command?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Where did you get `get-storagereliabilitycounter` from?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - Just googling. One of many: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60471603/how-to-get-all-s-m-a-r-t-data-of-storagespaces-physical-disks-on-net

Comment: I found a function that will extract SMART values: https://github.com/Fantastitech/GetSmartWin and a list of SMART values for NTFS/Windows: //www.cropel.com/library/smart-attribute-list.aspx ... This should work for what I'm doing. Thanks.